# OpenStreetMap tile opacity

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, openstreetmap

is there a way to set the opacity of just the tiles using leaflet and OpenStreetMap?
I want the map to have 50% opacity, but keep 100% opacity on the markers.

Setting opacity like this, does not work:

```
var bkgLayer = L.tileLayer.grayscale('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');

    var map = new L.Map("map", {
                center: new L.LatLng(-31.4, 50.9),
                scrollWheelZoom: false,
                  zoomControl: false,
                  zoom: 5,
                  opacity: 0.5,
                  layers: bkgLayer
              });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal Leaflet Tile Layer (Grid Layer) has the `opacity` option.

https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#gridlayer-opacity

In your case you are using a special Tile Layer with [Leaflet.TileLayer.Grayscale](https://github.com/Zverik/leaflet-grayscale/) plugin.

However it properly extends the normal Tile Layer behaviour, and its code does not seem to make it incompatible with the `opacity` option. Therefore it should simply work:

```js
var bkgLayer = L.tileLayer.grayscale('urlTemplate', {
  opacity: 0.75
});
```

Comment: That was exactly what i wanted, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.querySelector` to access the Leaflet tile pane and set the opacity through style:

```js
const element = document.querySelector(
  '.leaflet-tile-pane'
).style.opacity = 0.5;
```

[Here is a demo I put together](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-rqtxwt?file=index.js) on StackBlitz showing how to use [Leaflet-Slider](https://github.com/Eclipse1979/leaflet-slider) to adjust the opacity of the tile layer without altering the markers.